# Is there any way to bound the integral with mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

For small $s$, I try to find some coefficient $M=M(s)$ where for any smooth real function $f$

$$\int_0^1 (f(t+s)-f(t))dt=\int_0^1 s\cdot f'(\eta(t))dt\leq M\int_0^1 f'(t)dt$$

. In here, $\eta(t)$ is the real number satisfying

$$\frac{f(t+s)-f(t)}{s}=f'(\eta(t))$$
. I try to make some coefficient $M$, but it is hard to find. Could anyone help me?

Comment: This isn't really a likely formulation. $f'$ can be negative, for example; also, the values of $f$ between $1$ and $1+s$ can make the LHS enormous without changing the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear there can be no such inequality, because the first integral involves values of $f(x)$ for $x\notin(0,1)$. And it's clear the upper bound should be $M\int_0^1|f'(x)|\,dx$, since $M\int_0^1f'(x)\,dx=M(f(1)-f(0))$.

Perhaps (for $s>0$) we can get $\int_0^{1+s}(f(s+t)-f(t))\,dt\le M\int_0^1|f'(t)|\,dt$.

Using FTC seems more likely to work than MVT. $$\begin{align}\int_0^1(f(t+s)-f(t))\,dt&=\int_0^1\int_t^{t+s}f'(x)\,dx\,dt.
\end{align}$$

If you apply Fubini here you get three terms, due to the shape of the region. In each term the inner integral is trivial, of the form $\int_a^b f'(x)\,dt=(b-a)f'(x)$; put it together and you get $$\left|\int_0^1(f(t+s)-f(t))\,dt\right|\le s\int_0^{1+s}|f'(x)|\,dx.$$